# Implement row level security (RLS) in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

We are trying to implement Row Level Security in Azure Data Explorer (ADX). Out of the box, ADX doesn't provide RLS. Is there any way/ workaround we can implement RLS?

We are trying out below option but no success :

1. Creating 2 separate databases (**DbNonSecure**, **DbSecure**)
2. **DbNonSecure** is non-secured, all the rows can be accessible by an authenticated user
3. **DbSecure** is secured database and can not be accessible by anyone except AAD APP or some other service account
4. From DbNonSecure, we are thinking to call functions that access data in **DbSecure** (using AAD APP or Service Account) and check Row Level Security.

We couldn't find a way to call functions that access data in **DbSecure** using ADD APP or Service Account.

Also, we know we can add a middle tier (Separate UI) to achieve this but we don't have that much time freedom to develop middle tier.

Answer (score 0):

you're correct - Kusto/ADX doesn't support row level security at the moment (you can upvote the feature request @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice)

---

> We couldn't find a way to call functions that access data in DbSecure using ADD APP or Service Account.

AAD application authentication is a valid means of authentication to a Kusto/ADX database. There's a full guide on how to set that up here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/access-control/how-to-provision-aad-app

-> Once you've granted the required access to your AAD Application, it can be used for querying the database. Referencing stored functions is simply part of a query, and doesn't require any special setup (asides from, obviously, creating the stored function)

*Side note:* you may also find interest in the [Restricted view access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/restrictedviewaccesspolicy) (it may or may not fit your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, ADX Row Level Security is in preview now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy